# UnExpected output from mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using mongoose to connect and query mongoDB.

Now if I have the following code:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    mongoose.connection.db.collection('offer').aggregate([{
      $match: {
        $or: [
          {
            ccChecked: {
              $lt: new Date(currentDay + 'T00:00:00.000Z')
            }
          },
          {
            ccChecked: {
              $exists: 0
            }
          }
        ],
        _id: { $in: offerObjIds }
      }
    },
    { $sample: { size: 2 } }
    ], (err, res) => {
      console.log('res is', res);
      resolve(res);
    });
  });
```

The result provided is fine and we get the expected output.
But if we have the following query, and I provide SAMPLE_SIZE as 2:

```
const sampleSize = process.env.SAMPLE_SIZE
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    mongoose.connection.db.collection('offer').aggregate([{
      $match: {
        $or: [
          {
            ccChecked: {
              $lt: new Date(currentDay + 'T00:00:00.000Z')
            }
          },
          {
            ccChecked: {
              $exists: 0
            }
          }
        ],
        _id: { $in: offerObjIds }
      }
    },
    { $sample: { size: sampleSize } }
    ], (err, res) => {
      console.log('res is', res);
      resolve(res);
    });
  });
```

In this case, I get the result as undefined. Can someone provide explanation why such behaviour and how to resolve this through process.env variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that `sampleSize` is an integer. It could be string coming from `process.env` variables.

`{ $sample: { size: <positive integer> } }`

Update:
I tested out a script on my command line. See the results:

`set SAMPLE_SIZE=1&& node example.js`

example.js

```
console.log(process.env);
```

Output:

> { ... SAMPLE_SIZE: '1', ... }

Comment: If I pass it in npm script as "start-offer-service-dev": "SAMPLE_SIZE=2 node_modules/.bin/babel-node src/services/offerService/index.js", then would it be a string or a number?

Comment: Yup, my mistake, the arguments passed through npm script are of string type and thus have to be converted to int